# How to resize one of the plugins of the Flot library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, resize, flot

I'm displaying charts using the [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) library and almost all of them are working fine with the resize plugin.

Nevertheless, I need to start using one of the  extra-[plugins](http://en.benjaminbuffet.com/labs/flot/) that allows to display bars side by side. Since this is just a non-official plugin chart, I'm having a issue to use Flot's Resize Plugin and Benjamin's Bar-side-by-side Plugin. It's not working and I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined (jquery.flot.resize.js:51)
```

I need to make this resizing for this specific chart. Some help would be really appreciated. Somebody could tell me what could be done to fix this problem?

Edit: I'm adding two JsFiddle examples:

First, the bar chart example working correctly (but without the resize plugin). [Clcik Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmking/vQJZd/)
Second, the same bar chart example using the resize plugin. [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmking/DtmvM/)

Comment: Could you put a jsfiddle.net together demoing the problem?

Comment: Hi Mark, I've just put two jsfiddle's.. The first one works perfectly without the resize plugin, and the second one doesn't work because of the resize plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Flot (v. 0.6) referenced in both of your Fiddles is really old. The resize plugin ties into the shutdown hook in Flot:

```
plot.hooks.shutdown.push(shutdown);
```

Version 0.6 of Flot doesn't have the shutdown hook defined. The shutdown hook was added with version 0.7.

I updated the flot files referenced in your JSFiddle to the latest versions. Both the orderbars and resize plugin work as expected.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EDXh/1/)